Are terminals really not "software tools primarily used by programmers" (wording used on off-topic close box)
I've seen multiple people (including mods) imply that the reason for many terminal questions being closed as off-topic is that they are not "software tools primarily used by programmers".
(Whether it's "primarily" or "commonly" is discussed here: Is it tools used ... "Commonly By Programmers" or "Primarily For Programming"?))
I think it's hard to argue that terminals aren't used commonly by programmers. But I'm also surprised that some people seem to think that terminals aren't "primarily" used by programmers.
Maybe there's some ambiguity/misunderstanding about the word "primarily"? I would understand "primarily" in this context as "the majority of users".
Now even that is ambiguous, what do we mean by "users": one can define users as "has at least once used something", or alternatively as I would argue, one should define a user rather as "someone who frequently uses something".
Something that those who argue against terminals being "primarily used by programmers" say is that sysadmins use terminals a lot. That's true, but are there really more people who do sysadmin stuff with terminals on a given day than people who use the terminal as part of programming work? Maybe I'm underestimating the number of sysadmins and overestimate the number of programmers.
Also, if terminals are said to be not primarily used by programmers, then what about text editors like VS Code? I'm sure lots of sysadmins use VS Code, one can even use VS Code to write books, or edit a config file, etc. So I can't really see why terminal questions can be closed with reason "not a tool commonly/primarily used by programmers" when visual-studio-code questions aren't commonly closed with that reason.

"I think it's hard to argue that terminals aren't used commonly by programmers" is completely irrelevant, by that reason any OS question ever is on-topic because well you'd use an OS to program pretty much always so programmers commonly use OSs. They also commonly use chairs to sit on, and use a desk to sit in front of, …

Maybe a good rule of thumb is "was it designed to be used by programmers?" A terminal clearly is not, it's designed to be used by every user of a PC, it has been surpassed by GUI since then, but still the target audience is not programmers.

I commonly use a terminal for managing my headless home servers, such as my Plex server; does this mean I can start asking questions on [so] on how to manage by Plex Library files..? (No, no I can't.)

VS Code is an IDE, not a text editor. It has tools for running code, compiling code, debugging code, etc. Questions about a text editor (think Notepad) would likely by off-topic for SO.

I found 1, 2, 3, 4 questions about VS Code that were closed with that reason.

@AndrewT. thanks these are just bad questions that are also closeable for other reasins

VS Code is a tool built and developed to work with code. It's a code editor.
It is its primary function, and thus makes sense that its users are, first and foremost, programmers.
The terminal is simply a text-based interface to operate a computer. It's primary use case is not programming. It's operating the computer. Any user that needs to operate a computer using a text-based interface, would use the (a) terminal.
Any question about terminal usage that's not a programming question, is off-topic.

As an aside, I would argue that "terminal" on itself is not a good tag, as it's not generally useful to describe a question or to connect experts to a subject matter. Also, it routinely attracts off-topic questions. All that being said, this question is not actually about the tag existence itself.

From personal experience I struggle to picture programming with a terminal (emulator).  I use terminals regularly; the last time I programmed with one was probably decades ago, using an (actual) terminal to stuff Forth down a line to a SunOS monitor.

Any user that needs to operate a computer using a text-based interface, would use the (a) terminal. Would you not agree that the vast majority of such users in the current day are in fact programmers? The primary purpose of a terminal these days is for programmers doing programming-adjacent tasks. Their historically broader role is essentially obsolete.

No, I wouldn’t agree. Hence my answer up here. You may want to post an answer with a different perspective, @Jeremy

The terminal is used to run other stuff. The other stuff that's being run is far more important to determining whether or not the question is on topic.

@JeremyBanks "Would you not agree that the vast majority of such users in the current day are in fact programmers?" system administrators, devops, power users. I use a terminal but hardly "as a programmer" I most commonly use it to do some network administration (check and diagnose connectivity), automate some tasks that can be done with the OS,  and occasionally data wrangling (which a data scientist might do). I have done similar things before I learned programming.

@VLAZ how many sysadmins does a company have relative to programmers? Very few these days. devops are programmers. Power users who use the terminal are also way less common now that there is way more non terminal ways to power-use a computer. Your examples are not reflective of the modern state of computing.

How much of what a programmer does is actually typically done on the terminal? Not the programming, debugging or compiling, most use an IDE or editor with plugins, so what's actually left, that's programming related and typically done on the terminal?

@JeremyBanks our company has 2-3 or so to our 15 programmers. Of which 1-2 programmers use the command line. Me being one of them - most often ssh in to read the logs (I find it more convenient to look through them with less - the others just use an online dashboard that serves the same logs). I refuse to believe I do "programming" by 1. using ssh 2. doing less some/log/file.log Our devops also use the command line but to set up and command the docker cluster. I don't think doing health checks and deploying/restarting/provisioning the nodes counts as programming.

The interface to all of our embedded systems is a terminal. I am the only one who does any programming, but everyone who uses the system interacts with them via the terminal. Terminals are not "primarily" used by programmers/developers. This answer by yivi is exactly correct, and I feel I could scarcely have written it better myself. Code editors are tools primarily used by programmers; terminals are not. If the terminal question is in a programming/software development context, it's on-topic here. If not, then it's not. Pretty simple.

I wish we would just get rid of that whole tool thing, people will read that in whatever way fits their needs. It needs to be a programming problem. Keep it simple.
